# NFS mounted home dirs, Is it safe to restart the server's NFS service?

Tags: home-directory, nfs

The purpose of this NFS server is to provide all users consistent access to their files and settings by serving their home dirs.

The server is running Ubuntu 12 and the NFS config is at it's defaults.

There are 30 or so clients with a mix of NFSv4 and NFSv3 mounts. Some are set up via autofs, others via /etc/fstab entries.

We want to experiment with the NFS config but I don't want to cause problems with logged-in users.

Can we safely restart the NFS service? What might be some of the consequences for users? If this is likely to depend on exactly which settings we are changing, I'll note the first candidate is upping the RPCNFSDCOUNT from 8 to 64 as suggested in http://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/Useful-NFS-Options-for-Tuning-and-Management. We are experiencing some hanging clients during peak usage.